# Installing Development IOS-Deploy Tools Error

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

I'm running,
xcode-select --install

I'm getting this error however for node modules. can someone please tell me what I should do?

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'child-process-close'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:15:1
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:474:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

link to resource
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/ios/

not sure how i fix this? I just installed the latest version of node.js 7.2.0 with brew.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong so I removed the node modules,

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

then run

```
brew uninstall node
brew install node
```

Fixed the issue, was able to install after that no problem.